# How can I assign response in a variable from a post request?

Tags: node.js

I'm using node-fetch module. How can I store response in a variable for further use from the following post request ?

[node-fetch](https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch) git repo here.

```
var url = 'http://127.0.0.1:10010/login';
var data = {
    email : 'rajan10@gmail.com',
    password : 'sha256md5'
};

fetch(url, {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
}).then(res => res.json());
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, `then(res => res.json());` in this, res is the response. If you want to store it, just assign it to some variable before returning it.

```
var r;
...
.then(res => {
    r = res;
    res.json();
});
```

You can then use `r` as per your needs.

Comment: For async behaviour before assigning in r next statements outside of fetch executes. what can be done ?

Comment: That is how async behvaior works, right? It won't wait for the content to be available before moving forward. If you want to wait for the response here, nest your corresponding code inside the `.then(..)` and it'll execute when the response is available.